# Increase the font in a table whilst fitting it in a page

Tags: tables, longtable, multicolumn, multirow, longtabu

I have inserted a table in my article but the font is too small. How can I increase it without affecting the scale of the table? I tried different ways but the table is out the page.

My table looks like the below picture:

[image]

```
'''

    \begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Comparative Study in The Related Work of Sentiment Analysis}
\normalsize
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{lllllll} 
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Ref.}}                         & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Language}}      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Dataset}}                                             & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{algorithm}}            & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Polarity}}                                                                     & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{Performance}\\\textbf{( Acc.)}\end{tabular}}  \\\cline{3-4}
                                                       &                                         & \textbf{Name/Types}                                   & \textbf{Size}            &                                                &                                                                                                        &                                                                                                  \\ 
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\cite{AlSalman2020}}                       & \multirow{2}{*}{Arabic}                 & \multirow{2}{*}{Tweets}                               & \multirow{2}{*}{2000}    & \multirow{2}{*}{Discriminative multinomial NB} & Positive                                                                                               & \multirow{2}{*}{87.50\%}                                                                         \\
                                                       &                                         &                                                       &                          &                                                & Negative                                                                                               &                                                                                                  \\
\addlinespace
\multirow{3}{*}{\cite{IKAUNIECE2018}}                      & \multirow{3}{*}{Spanish and Catalan}    & \multirow{3}{*}{Student feedback}                     & \multirow{3}{*}{2925}    & \multirow{2}{*}{SVM}                           & Positive                                                                                               
& \multirow{2}{*}{71\%}                                                                            \\
                                                       &                                         &                                                       &                          &                                                & Negative                                                                                               &                                                                                                  \\
                                                       &                                         &                                                       &                          & Logistic regression                            & neutral                                                                                                & 72\%                                                                                             \\
\addlinespace
\multirow{3}{*}{\cite{Sengkey2019}}  & \multirow{3}{*}{Indonesian and English} & \multirow{3}{*}{Student feedback documents}           & \multirow{3}{*}{636}     & \multirow{3}{*}{SVM}                           & Positive                                                                                               & \multirow{3}{*}{74\%}                                                                            \\
                                                       &                                         &                                                       &                          &                                                & Negative                                                                                               &                                                                                                  \\
                                                       &                                         &                                                       &                          &                                                & neutral                                                                                                &                                                                                                  \\
\addlinespace
\multirow{3}{*}{(\cite{Kamiş}}             & \multirow{3}{*}{English}                & \multirow{3}{*}{SemEval}                              & \multirow{3}{*}{32000}   & CNN                                            & Positive                                                                                               & \multirow{3}{*}{59\% on CNN +LSTM}                                                               \\
                                                       &                                         &                                                       &                          & LSTM                                           & Negative                                                                                               &                                                                                                  \\
                                                       &                                         &                                                       &                          & CNN + LSTM                                     & neutral                                                                                                &                                                                                                  \\
\addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{\cite{Munna2020}}   & \multirow{2}{*}{Bangla}                 & \multirow{2}{*}{Online shops reviews}                 & \multirow{2}{*}{5109}    & \multirow{2}{*}{DNN}                           & Good,  Bad                                                                                             & 84\%                                                                                             \\
                                                       &                                         &                                                       &                          &                                                & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Complain\\Recommended\\Wrong delivery Appreciation\end{tabular}             & 69\%                                                                                             \\
\addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{\cite{Al-Bayati}} & \multirow{2}{*}{Arabic}                 & \multirow{2}{*}{LABR}                                 & \multirow{2}{*}{14448}   & \multirow{2}{*}{LSTM}                          & 0                                                                                                      & \multirow{2}{*}{82\%}                                                                            \\
                                                       &                                         &                                                       &                          &                                                & 1                                                                                                      &                                                                                                  \\
\addlinespace
\multirow{4}{*}{\cite{Al-Hassan}}       & \multirow{4}{*}{Arabic}                 & \multirow{4}{*}{Tweets}                               & \multirow{4}{*}{11000}   & LSTM                                           & \multirow{4}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}none, religious\\racial, sexism\\general hate\end{tabular}} & \multirow{4}{*}{72\% on LSTM + CNN}                                                              \\
                                                       &                                         &                                                       &                          & LSTM+CNN                                       &                                                                                                        &                                                                                                  \\
                                                       &                                         &                                                       &                          & GRU                                            &                                                                                                        &                                                                                                  \\
                                                       &                                         &                                                       &                          & GRU+CNN                                        &                                                                                                        &                                                                                                  \\
\addlinespace
\multirow{10}{*}{\cite{Onan2020}}                          & \multirow{10}{*}{English}               & \multirow{10}{*}{Student feedback}                    & \multirow{10}{*}{154000} & NB                                             & \multirow{10}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Positive\\~Negative\end{tabular}}                          & \multirow{10}{*}{98.29\% on RNN}                                                                 \\
                                                       &                                         &                                                       &                          & SVM                                            &                                                                                                        &                                                                                                  \\
                                                       &                                         &                                                       &                          & LR                                             &                                                                                                        &                                                                                                  \\
                                                       &                                         &                                                       &                          & KNN                                            &                                                                                                        &                                                                                                  \\
                                                       &                                         &                                                       &                          & FR                                             &                                                                                                        &                                                                                                  \\
                                                       &                                         &                                                       &                          & CNN                                            &                                                                                                        &                                                                                                  \\
                                                       &                                         &                                                       &                          & RNN                                            &                                                                                                        &                                                                                                  \\
                                                       &                                         &                                                       &                          & RNN-AM                                         &                                                                                                        &                                                                                                  \\
                                                       &                                         &                                                       &                          & GRU                                            &                                                                                                        &                                                                                                  \\
                                                       &                                         &                                                       &                          & LSTM                                           &                                                                                                        &                                                                                                  \\
\addlinespace
\multirow{4}{*}{\cite{Alshutayri}}              & \multirow{4}{*}{Arabic}                 & \multirow{4}{*}{Tweets}                               & \multirow{4}{*}{32186}   & NB                                             & \multirow{4}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Positive\\~Negative\\~Neutral\end{tabular}}                 & \multirow{4}{*}{70\% on LSTM}                                                                    \\
                                                       &                                         &                                                       &                          & Logistic regression                            &                                                                                                        &                                                                                                  \\
                                                       &                                         &                                                       &                          & SVM                                            &                                                                                                        &                                                                                                  \\
                                                       &                                         &                                                       &                          & LSTM                                           &                                                                                                        &                                                                                                  \\
\addlinespace
\multirow{5}{*}{\cite{Chouikhi2021}}  & \multirow{5}{*}{Arabic}                 & ASTD                                                  & 10K                      & \multirow{5}{*}{Arabic BERT}                   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Pos,Neg\\Neu,Mix\end{tabular}                                               & 91\%                                                                                             \\
                                                       &                                         & HARD                                                  & 93.7k                    &                                                & Pos,Neg,Neu                                                                                            & 95\%                                                                                             \\
                                                       &                                         & LABR                                                  & 63k                      &                                                & 0,1                                                                                                    & 87\%                                                                                             \\
                                                       &                                         & AJGT                                                  & 1800                     &                                                & Pos, neg                                                                                               & 96.60\%                                                                                          \\
                                                       &                                         & ArSenTD-Lev                                           & 4000                     &                                                & Used 3 classes of 5                                                                                    & 75\%                                                                                             \\
\addlinespace
\multirow{5}{*}{\cite{Alsuhemi2022}}                & \multirow{5}{*}{Arabic}                 & \multirow{5}{*}{restaurant, movies, products reviews} & \multirow{5}{*}{7686}    & LR                                             & \multirow{5}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Positive\\Negative\end{tabular}}                            & 83\%                                                                                             \\
                                                       &                                         &                                                       &                          & RF                                             &                                                                                                        & 82\%                                                                                             \\
                                                       &                                         &                                                       &                          & NB                                             &                                                                                                        & 84\%                                                                                             \\
                                                       &                                         &                                                       &                          & SVM                                            &                                                                                                        & 83\%                                                                                             \\
                                                       &                                         &                                                       &                          & araBERT                                        &                                                                                                        & 82\%                                                                                             \\
\addlinespace
\cite{ElMoubtahij}                & Arabic                                  & ARev                                                  & 40K                      & araBERT                                        & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Positive\\Negative\end{tabular}                                             & 92.50\%                                                                                          \\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
```

'''

**Eidet**
I when I edit my table I faced this issue the content of cell does not fit the cell like:
[image]

```
\begingroup
\small\linespread{0.9}\selectfont
\sisetup{group-minimum-digits=4}
    \begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Comparative Study in The Related Work of Sentiment Analysis},
  label = {RW},
                    ]{colsep  = 4pt,
                      colspec = {@{} l  X[0.8, l]  X[1.2, l] Q[c, si={table-format=6.0}]
                                       X[1.2, l]       X[l] X[0.8, l] @{}},
                     row{1,2}= {guard, font=\footnotesize\bfseries},
                     rowsep  = 4pt,
                     rowhead = 2
                    }
    \toprule
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    Ref. 
    &   \SetCell[r=2]{l}    Language 
        &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    Dataset
            &   &    \SetCell[r=2]{l}Algorithm
                    &   \SetCell[r=2]{l}    Polarity
                        &   \SetCell[r=2]{l}    Performance (Acc.)      
                                                    \\
    \cmidrule[lr]{3-4}
    &   &   Name/Types 
            &   Size 
                &   &   &                           \\ 
    \midrule
\cite{AlSalman2020}
    &   Arabic 
        &   Tweets 
            &   2000 
                &   Discriminative multinomial NB 
                    & {Positive\\ Negative} 
                        &   \qty{87.5}{\percent}    \\
\cite{IKAUNIECE2018}
    &   Spanish and Catalan
        &   Student feedback
            &   2925
                &   {SVM\\  Logistic regression} 
                    &   {Positive\\ Negative\\ neutral} 
                        &   {\qty{71}{\percent}\\
                             \qty{72}{\percent}}    \\
\cite{Sengkey2019}
    &   Indonesian and English 
        &   Student feedback documents 
            &   636 
                &   SVM 
                    &   {Positive\\ Negative\\ neutral} 
                        &   \qty{74}{\percent}      \\
\cite{Kamiş} 
    &   English
        &   SemEval
            &   32000
                &   {CNN\\  LSTM\\ CNN + LSTM}
                    &   {Positive\\ Negative\\ neutral} 
                        &   \qty{59}{\percent}  on CNN + LSTM   
                                                    \\
\cite{Munna2020} 
    &   Bangla
        &   Online shops reviews
            &   5109
                &   DNN
                    &   {Good,\\  Bad} 
                        &  \qty{84}{\percent}       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   Complain, Recommended Wrong  delivery, Appreciation
                        &   \qty{69}{\percent}      \\

\cite{Al-Bayati}
    &   Arabic 
        &   LABR 
            &   14448 
                &   LSTM 
                    &   {0\\ 1} 
                        &   \qty{82}{\percent}      \\
\cite{Al-Hassan} 
    &   Arabic
        &   Tweets
            &   11000
                &   LSTM, LSTM+CNN, GRU, GRU+CNN
                    &   {none, religious,\\  racial, sexism,\\  general hate}
                        &   \qty{72}{\percent} on LSTM + CNN    
                                                    \\

\cite{Onan2020} 
    &   English
        &   Student feedback
            &   154000
                &   NB, SVM, LR, KNN, FR, CNN, RNN, RNN-AM,  GRU, LSTM
                    &   {Positive,\\ Negative} 
                        &    \qty{98.29}{\percent} on RNN     
                                                    \\
\cite{Alshutayri} 
    &   Arabic
        &   Tweets
            &   32186
                &   NB, Logistic regression, SVM, LSTM
                    &   {Positive,\\ Negative,\\ Neutral}
                        &   \qty{70}{\percent} on LSTM 
                                                    \\
\cite{Chouikhi2021} 
    &   Arabic
        &   {ASTD\\ HARD\\ LABR\\ AJGT\\ ArSenTD\\ Lev}
            &   {10K\\ 93.7K\\ 63K\\ 1800\\\ 4000}
                &   Arabic BERT
                    &   {Pos, Neg, Neu, Mix\\ pos, neg, neu\\0, 1\\ pos, neg \\ used 3 classes from 5 } 
                        &  { \qty{91}{\percent}\\ 95\%\\ 87\%\\96.6\%\\ 75\% }
                                             \\
 \cite{Alsuhemi2022}
       & Arabic
          & restaurant, movies, products reviews
              & 7686
                    & {LR\\ RF\\ NB\\ SVM\\ araBERT}
                         & positive, negative
                                & {83\% \\ 82\% \\ 84\% \\ 83\% \\ 82\%}
                                                                     \\

\cite{ElMoubtahij}
           & Arabic
                & ARev
                     & 40000
                         & araBERT
                              & poditive, negative
                                         & 92.5\%   \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{longtblr}
\endgroup
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/5764)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- In your table code is very easy went to lost ... Also image of table is poor quality, so reading data from it is impossible.
- So, I edit few first eleven rows of your table. In this effort may happen, that I misunderstood what belong to some rows. Especially because table code is not consistent
- Anyway, MWE below may serve as skeleton and example how to edit rest of your table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[skip=1ex,
            font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}      
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Mx wide table}
    \label{tab:my-table}
\small\linespread{0.9}\selectfont
\sisetup{group-minimum-digits=4}
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} l  X[0.8, l,m]  X[1.2, l,m] Q[c, si={table-format=6.0}] 
                               X[1.2, l,m]       X[l,m] X[0.8, l,m] @{}},
             row{1,2}= {guard, font=\footnotesize\bfseries, m},
             rowsep  = 4pt
             }
    \toprule
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    Ref. 
    &   \SetCell[r=2]{l}    Language 
        &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    Dataset
            &   &    \SetCell[r=2]{l}Algorithm
                    &   \SetCell[r=2]{l}    Polarity
                        &   \SetCell[r=2]{l}    Performance (Acc.)      
                                                    \\
    \cmidrule[lr]{3-4}
    &   &   Name/Types 
            &   Size 
                &   &   &                           \\ 
    \midrule
\cite{AlSalman 2020}
    &   Arabic 
        &   Tweets 
            &   2000 
                &   Discriminative multinomial NB 
                    & {Positive\\ Negative} 
                        &   \qty{87.5}{\percent}    \\
\cite{IKAUNIECE 2018}
    &   Spanish and Catalan
        &   Student feedback
            &   2925
                &   {SVM\\  Logistic regression} 
                    &   {Positive\\ Negative\\ neutral} 
                        &   {\qty{71}{\percent}\\
                             \qty{72}{\percent}}    \\
\cite{Sengkey, Jacobus, and Manoppo 2019}
    &   Indonesian and English 
        &   Student feedback documents 
            &   636 
                &   SVM 
                    &   {Positive\\ Negative\\ neutral} 
                        &   \qty{74}{\percent}      \\
\cite{Kamiş and Goularas 2019} 
    &   English
        &   SemEval
            &   32000
                &   {CNN\\  LSTM\\ CNN + LSTM}
                    &   {Positive\\ Negative\\ neutral} 
                        &   \qty{59}{\percent}  on CNN + LSTM   
                                                    \\
\cite{Munna, Rifat, and Badrudduza 2020} 
    &   Bangla
        &   Online shops reviews
            &   5109
                &   DNN
                    &   {Good,\\  Bad} 
                        &  \qty{84}{\percent}       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   Complain, Recommended Wrong  delivery, Appreciation
                        &   \qty{69}{\percent}      \\

\cite{Al-Bayati, Al-Araji, and Ameen 2020}
    &   Arabic 
        &   LABR 
            &   14448 
                &   LSTM 
                    &   {0\\ 1} 
                        &   \qty{82}{\percent}      \\
\cite{Al-Hassan and Al-Dossari 2021} 
    &   Arabic
        &   Tweets
            &   11000
                &   LSTM, LSTM+CNN, GRU, GRU+CNN
                    &   {none, religious,\\  racial, sexism,\\  general hate}
                        &   \qty{72}{\percent} on LSTM + CNN    
                                                    \\

\cite{Onan 2020} 
    &   English
        &   Student feedback
            &   154000
                &   NB, SVM, LR, KNN, FR, CNN, RNN, RNN-AM,  GRU, LSTM
                    &   {Positive,\\ Negative} 
                        &    \qty{98.29}{\percent} on RNN     
                                                    \\
\cite{Alshutayri et al. n.d.} 
    &   Arabic
        &   Tweets
            &   32186
                &   NB, Logistic regression, SVM, LSTM
                    &   {Positive,\\ Negative,\\ Neutral}
                        &   \qty{70}{\percent} on LSTM 
                                                    \\
\cite{Chouikhi, Chniter, and Jarray 2021} 
    &   Arabic
        &   ASTD 
            &   10000
                &   Arabic BERT
                    &   Positive, Negative, Neutral, Mix 
                        &   \qty{9}{\percent}   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit (1):**

- In the case, that your table is longer than one page, you need to replace `tblr` with `longtblr`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[skip=1ex,
            font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begingroup
\small\linespread{0.9}\selectfont
\sisetup{group-minimum-digits=4}
    \begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Comparative Study in The Related Work of Sentiment Analysis},
  label = {tab:my-table},
                    ]{colsep  = 4pt,
                      colspec = {@{} l  X[0.8, l]  X[1.2, l] Q[c, si={table-format=6.0}]
                                       X[1.2, l]       X[l] X[0.8, l] @{}},
                     row{1,2}= {guard, font=\footnotesize\bfseries},
                     rowsep  = 4pt,
                     rowhead = 2
                    }
    \toprule
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    Ref.
    &   \SetCell[r=2]{l}    Language
        &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    Dataset
            &   &    \SetCell[r=2]{l}Algorithm
                    &   \SetCell[r=2]{l}    Polarity
                        &   \SetCell[r=2]{l}    Performance (Acc.)
                                                    \\
    \cmidrule[lr]{3-4}
    &   &   Name/Types
            &   Size
                &   &   &                           \\
    \midrule
%% table body
\cite{AlSalman 2020}
    &   Arabic
        &   Tweets
            &   2000
                &   Discriminative multinomial NB
                    & {Positive\\ Negative}
                        &   \qty{87.5}{\percent}    \\
\cite{IKAUNIECE 2018}
    &   Spanish and Catalan
        &   Student feedback
            &   2925
                &   {SVM\\  Logistic regression}
                    &   {Positive\\ Negative\\ neutral}
                        &   {\qty{71}{\percent}\\
                             \qty{72}{\percent}}    \\
\cite{Sengkey, Jacobus, and Manoppo 2019}
    &   Indonesian and English
        &   Student feedback documents
            &   636
                &   SVM
                    &   {Positive\\ Negative\\ neutral}
                        &   \qty{74}{\percent}      \\
\cite{Kamiş and Goularas 2019}
    &   English
        &   SemEval
            &   32000
                &   {CNN\\  LSTM\\ CNN + LSTM}
                    &   {Positive\\ Negative\\ neutral}
                        &   \qty{59}{\percent}  on CNN + LSTM
                                                    \\
\cite{Munna, Rifat, and Badrudduza 2020}
    &   Bangla
        &   Online shops reviews
            &   5109
                &   DNN
                    &   {Good,\\  Bad}
                        &  \qty{84}{\percent}       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   Complain, Recommended Wrong  delivery, Appreciation
                        &   \qty{69}{\percent}      \\

\cite{Al-Bayati, Al-Araji, and Ameen 2020}
    &   Arabic
        &   LABR
            &   14448
                &   LSTM
                    &   {0\\ 1}
                        &   \qty{82}{\percent}      \\
\cite{Al-Hassan and Al-Dossari 2021}
    &   Arabic
        &   Tweets
            &   11000
                &   LSTM, LSTM+CNN, GRU, GRU+CNN
                    &   {none, religious,\\  racial, sexism,\\  general hate}
                        &   \qty{72}{\percent} on LSTM + CNN
                                                    \\

\cite{Onan 2020}
    &   English
        &   Student feedback
            &   154000
                &   NB, SVM, LR, KNN, FR, CNN, RNN, RNN-AM,  GRU, LSTM
                    &   {Positive,\\ Negative}
                        &    \qty{98.29}{\percent} on RNN
                                                    \\
\cite{Alshutayri et al. n.d.}
    &   Arabic
        &   Tweets
            &   32186
                &   NB, Logistic regression, SVM, LSTM
                    &   {Positive,\\ Negative,\\ Neutral}
                        &   \qty{70}{\percent} on LSTM
                                                    \\
\cite{Chouikhi, Chniter, and Jarray 2021}
    &   Arabic
        &   ASTD
            &   10000
                &   Arabic BERT
                    &   Positive, Negative, Neutral, Mix
                        &   \qty{9}{\percent}       \\
\cite{Alsuhemi2022}
    &   Arabic
        &   restaurant, movies, products reviews
            &   7686
                &   {LR\\ RF\\ NB\\ SVM\\ araBERT}
                    &   {positive\\Negative}                            
                        &   {\qty{83}{\percent} \\
                             \qty{82}{\percent} \\  
                             \qty{84}{\percent} \\  
                             \qty{83}{\percent} \\  
                             \qty{82}{\percent}}    \\   
\cite{ElMoubtahij}                
    & Arabic 
        & ARev 
            & 40000 
                & araBERT 
                    &   {Positive\\ Negative}                                             
                        &   \qty{92.50}{\percent}   \\  
    \bottomrule
    \end{longtblr}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

- In above MWE I added rest of rows from edited table in your question.
- Due to used `\small` font size and reduced `linespread` size table can be dit in one page, but for case, that your table still have more rows, it is now designed as long table, which can be spread over many pages.
- Long table should not be enclosed in `˙table` float. If it is, it will not be broken between pages but will protrude out of bottom of page.
- For eventual further help you need to inform me (us) about the following:

  - does format of table produced with both MWE is what you after (first MWE (Minimal Working Example) produce vertical centered cells columns, in the second contents are top aligned)?
  - in comment you said that you got some errors, but from it is not clear, if with proposed solution or with inserting it in your document
  - what errors you got?

*Note*: please (again), always provide complete small, but complete document, which we can compile as it is. With this you inform use about page layout, which (to problem relevant) packages you use, etc.

[image]

**Edit (2):**

- Apparently we don't speak the same language since so far my guessing what you after was wrong ...
- So I'm still not sure if now I correctly figured out what you like to tell me. Cells as for example is

```
NB, SVM, LR, KNN, FR, CNN, RNN, RNN-AM,  GRU, LSTM
```

you like that  shortens be below each other.

- This is simple to achieve:

```
{NB\\ SVM\\ LR\\ KNN\\ FR\\ CNN\\ RNN\\ RNN-AM\\  GRU\\ LSTM}
```

- The same you should do in all other cells where you like to have abbreviation written on the same way. This changes of table code I left you to do.
- After this correction your table (as you provide code in question) still can be fit on one page:

[image]

Comment: it worked but the my data is too long so I used longeTable then there are an error I cannot understand it. I put MWE if you can help me @Zarko

Comment: @HudaAlamoudi, if your table is longer than one page, than instead of `tblr` you should use `longtblr` which can be span over several pages if needed (see edited answer). For any further help you first need to extend your code fragment to small but complete document which can be compiled as it is. About errors: what error you get? At compiling of proposed  solution? Anyway, first I need to know, if table form given my MWE is what you looking for.

Comment: Thank it works... but I have a question, How can I enable the size column to multiple lines like the algorithms column?

Comment: @HudaAlamoudi, sorry, I don't understand your comment. If you have new problem, please ask new follows-up question where you can add link to this one and by some sketch show us, what is new problem. BTW, you got two answers which bot solve your question as is. It my be a time that you accept one (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answers), which you estimate that solve a question on the best way.

Comment: I edited the question to illustrate my issue with BTW @zarko

Answer (score 3):

I suppose the title of your query, "Increase the font [size]" could be changed to "stop reducing the font size", because serious font size reduction is exactly what `\resizebox` does. In short: don't use `\resizebox` unless you secretly despise the readers of your papers.

Since automatic line breaking would appear to be required in 6 of the 7 columns of the, and because the table's length comfortably exceeds one page, I suggest you switch from a regular `tabular` environment to an `xltabular` environment and let line breaks occur wherever deemed necessary. In essence, an `xltabular` environment is a `longtable` environment that knows about the `X` column type.

The following screenshot shows the first few lines of the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in,letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{xltabular,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X}

\begin{document}

\begingroup % limit scope of next instruction to current TeX group
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % default value: 6pt
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} LLL l LLL @{}}
\caption{Table caption\strut} \label{tab:my-table} \\
\toprule
  Reference & Language & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Dataset} & Algorithm & Polarity & Performance (Acc.) \\ 
  \cmidrule(lr){3-4}
  & & Name\slash Types & Size \\ 
  \midrule
  \endfirsthead
  
  \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{Table \thetable, cont'd}\\[0.5ex]
  \toprule
  Reference & Language & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Dataset} & Algorithm & Polarity & Performance (Acc.) 
  \\ 
  \cmidrule(lr){3-4}
  & & Name\slash Types & Size \\ 
  \midrule
  \endhead
  
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{7}{r@{}}{\footnotesize (continued on following page)}\\
  \endfoot
  
  \bottomrule
  \endlastfoot
  
  
  AlSalman (2020) & Arabic & Tweets & 2000 & Discriminative multinomial NB & Positive\slash Negative & 87.5\% \\ 
  \addlinespace
  IKAUNIECE (2018) & Spanish and Catalan & Student feedback & 2925 & SVM & Positive\slash Negative\slash neutral & 71\ \\
  & & & & Logistic regression & & 72\% \\ 
  \addlinespace
  Sengkey, Jacobus, and Manoppo (2019) & Indonesian and English & Student feedback documents & 636 & SVM & Positive\slash Negative \newline neutral & 74\% \\ 
  \addlinespace
  Kamiş and Goularas (2019) & English & SemEval & 32000 & CNN & Positive\slash Negative\slash neutral & 59\% on CNN+LSTM \\
  & & & & LSTM & & \\
  & & & & CNN + LSTM & & \\ 
  \addlinespace
  Munna, Rifat, and Badrudduza (2020) & Bangla & Online shops reviews & 5109 & DNN & Good, Bad & 84\% \\
  & & & & & Complain, Recommended, Wrong  delivery, Appreciation & 69\% \\ 
  \addlinespace
  Al-Bayati, Al-Araji, and Ameen (2020) & Arabic & LABR & 14448 & LSTM & 0, 1 & 82\% \\ 
  \addlinespace
  Al-Hassan and Al-Dossari (2021) & Arabic & Tweets & 11000 & LSTM & none, religious, racial, sexism, general hate & 72\% on LSTM + CNN \\
  & & & & LSTM+CNN & & \\
  & & & & GRU & & \\
  & & & & GRU+CNN & & \\ 
  \addlinespace
  Onan (2020) & English & Student feedback & 154000 & NB & Positive, Negative & 98.29\% on RNN \\
  & & & & SVM & & \\
  & & & & LR  & & \\
  & & & & KNN & & \\
  & & & & FR  & & \\
  & & & & CNN & & \\
  & & & & RNN & & \\
  & & & & RNN-AM & & \\
  & & & & GRU & & \\
  & & & & LSTM & & \\ 
  \addlinespace
  Alshutayri et~al.\ (n.d.) & Arabic & Tweets & 32186 & NB &
  Positive, Negative, Neutral & 70\% on LSTM \\
  & & & & Logistic regression & & \\
  & & & & SVM  & & \\
  & & & & LSTM & & \\ 
  \addlinespace
  Chouikhi, Chniter, and Jarray (2021) & Arabic & ASTD & 10K & Arabic BERT & Pos, Neg, Neu, Mix & 91\% \\
  & & HARD & 93.7k & & Pos, Neg, Neu & 95\% \\
  & & LABR & 63k & & 0, 1 & 87\% \\
  & & AJGT & 1800 & & Pos, neg & 96.6\% \\
  & & ArSenTD-Lev & 4000 & & Used 3 classes of 5 & 75\% \\ 
  \addlinespace
  Alsuhemi et~al.\ (2022) & Arabic & restaurant, movies, product reviews & 7686 & LR & Positive, Negative & 83\% \\
  & & & & RF & & 82\% \\
  & & & & NB & & 84\% \\
  & & & & SVM & & 83\% \\
  & & & & araBERT & & 82\% \\  
  \addlinespace
  el Moubtahij, Abdelali, and Tazi (2022) & Arabic & ARev & 40K & araBERT & Positive, negative & 92.5\% \\
  
\end{xltabular}
\endgroup % cf. "\begingroup" directive above

\end{document}
```